# JSON how to check @me belong to particular SharePoint group

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, modern-experience, groups, json-formatting

How can I check in JSON that current user `@me` belongs to particular SharePoint admin group if its does not belong hide the column.

```
"customRowAction": {
    "action": "setValue",
    "actionInput": {
        "PersonColumnInteranalName": "@me"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot check SharePoint group membership using JSON formatting.

`setValue` can only be used to update the list item with the field values provided inside `actionInput`.

**Documentation**: [JSON formatting syntax reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference)

---

**Update (Additional info)**:

Using JSON formatting, you can check if user belong to a "Person or Group" column from same SharePoint list. Check below samples as reference for this:

1. [Highlight the current user](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/column-samples/person-currentuser)
2. [Highlight the current user - multi-person-currentuser](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/column-samples/multi-person-currentuser)