# Show hide columns based on the logged in user using JSON formaating

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, powerapp

I have a **custom SharePoint Group**, there are many members in that group. And a group of certain columns in my list that only should be shown to these **custom SharePoint Group** members.

I am thinking of a way to implement it like this - when opening the list form check the currently logged-in user whether presents in the **custom SharePoint Group** or not, if presents, show those certain columns otherwise hide it.

Is there any example of doing this in the show hide column conditionally using JSON formatting in SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot check SharePoint group membership using JSON formatting.

To achieve your requirements, you have to customize the list form using Power apps.

**Similar thread**: [JSON how to check @me belong to particular SharePoint group](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/299456/json-how-to-check-me-belong-to-particular-sharepoint-group/299458#299458)

---

For Power apps approach, check below links for more information:

1. [PowerApps Rule (hide or disable if you are not in a particular Group)?](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/power-apps-power-automate/powerapps-rule-hide-or-disable-if-you-are-not-in-a-particular/m-p/146868)
2. [Check if User is Member of SharePoint Group in Power Apps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dIzOAbMjN7g)